# Retrieving the list of the airports should only happen once every 5 minutes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on one of the projects and facing one problem.

I need to retrieve the list of airports from the external API using `HttpClient`. So that part was done with following code

```
public string URL = @"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrooksuk/JSON-Airports/master/airports.json";

public async Task<IEnumerable<Airport>> getAirportData()
{
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(URL);
    var stream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Airport>));
}
```

Airport.cs:

```
public class Airport
{
    public string iso { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem is: retrieving the list of the airports should only happen once every 5 minutes. A response header should be used to indicate whether the application got its data from the JSON feed

The name of the response header should be ‘from-feed’.

Could someone please help how to do that?

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and what part of your code do you need help with?

Comment: You need the ability to cache the response along with a timestamp indicating when the cache was last updated, and some simple logic to decide whether to populate the cached data or just return it.

Comment: How would we use reponse header to indicate whether we got the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` which is a Memory Cache storage. You are able to store values and then retrieve them later.

(note: You will need to add the `System.Runtime.Caching` reference by right-clicking References -> Add References -> Assemblies and scrolling down the list)

The following code assumes it is in a Controller and you have `using System.Runtime.Caching` at the top of the file

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Airport>> GetAirportDataAsync()
{
    var cacheKey = "airport-data";
    var headerName = "from-feed";

    // Safe cast to IEnumerable - Get returns null if the item does not exist in the cache
    var data = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as IEnumerable<Airport>;

    if (data == null)
    {
        Response.Headers.Add(headerName, "true");

        // Utilize your existing logic to get the data from the API
        data = await getAirportDataFromApiAsync();

        // Only cache for 5 minutes by providing the expiration time as now + 5 minutes
        var expiresAt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);

        // Stores the data read from the API into the cache
        MemoryCache.Default.Add(new CacheItem(cacheKey, data),
            new CacheItemPolicy
            {
                AbsoluteExpiration = expiresAt
            });

        return data;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Headers.Add(headerName, "false");

        return data;
    }
}
```